# Using JdbcLockRegistry from different threads to lock and unlock based on lockKey

Tags: multithreading, mutex, spring-jdbc, locks, temporal-workflow

We are using the Temporal framework to run several workflows. Due to the design of the application I cannot return Lock instance to the main method which starts all the workflows and hence I am relying on `JdbcLockRegistry` and same `lock_keys`.

Now this is how my `DatabaseLockManager.java` looks like,

```
public class DatabaseLockManager {

private final JdbcLockRegistry lockRegistry;

@Autowired
public DatabaseLockManager(JdbcLockRegistry lockRegistry){
  this.lockRegistry = lockRegistry;
}

public void acquire(String lockKey){
  jdbcLockRegistry.obtain(lockKey).lock();
}

public void release(String lockKey){
  jdbcLockRegistry.obtain(lockKey).unlock();
}
```

My Parent workflow calls the `acquire` method and `release` methods independently. I can run it successfully locally but when running over GCP, during the `release` method call, I am running into the following exception

```
"Mutex is not held by the current Thread"
```

Fix1
Now I tried using `ReneableLocks` but the output remains the same. I can see the entry against the lock_key in the database during the `acquire` method call and after a while, it will disappear as it is more like a `lease` but it is not due to my `release` method call.

I cannot use the traditional locking/unlocking here, because the `release` method has to be called after all the workflows are done which is managed by `Temporal`. Also, my microservice which is responsible for acquiring the releasing locks is different from the one that initiates workflows. Since `Locks` are not serializable I cannot even pass them from the first microservice to another.

Fix2
Also the `TTL` for `lockRegistry` is set to 30 minutes and my operation finishes in 5 mins.

Fix3
I cannot use `Semaphores` because there is another application that will use the same `lockKey` to fetch the locks on the same entity objects. My microservice is contending with this other application.

Comment: It's not clear to me how "your parent workflow" is acquiring this lock, and then releasing it… Do you make a call to `DatabaseLockManager` directly from your workflow code? Or is it using an activity/local activity?

Comment: I make a call to DatabaseLockManager with the lock_key for acquiring and releasing the locks from the parent workflow. It does not use any activity/local activity. (sry for the delay in the response)

Comment: Is there a way to generate the same `UUID` from the `lock_key` that Spring Integration does? I was thinking to use the database to unlock by removing the entry from `int_lock` table for the `lock_key`. However, spring does not store the `lock_key` as is and converts to `UUID` format before storing in the DB. I went through the code in detail for `DefaultLockRepository` but have not found anything useful. Maybe for the same reason spring does not want me to see that code.